# Extra trailing closure passed in call - Task showing error

Tags: swift, task

I'm pretty new to Swift, and attempting to convert a program in c# to swift, and I'm receiving the following error whenever I try to use a Task.

I tried to make the button's action function async, and ran into more errors, and read that one should use a wrapper function. Thus the following code is my attempt..

```
@IBAction func noteBrowser_button(_ sender: Any){        
    Task{
        await load_noteBrowserScreen()
    }
}
func load_noteBrowserScreen()async throws {
    do{
        if ( try await Server.serverVersion() >= Server.retrieveCustomerLimit )
        {
            //screen to change to
            let screen = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Note_Browser") as UIViewController?
            
            //show screen
            show(screen!, sender: self)
        }
        else
        {
            Popup.showMessage(parent: Popup.parent,
                              title: "Server Update Required",
                              msg: "Your server needs updated to enable this feature.")
        }
    }
    catch {}
}
```

Comment: why use Task ? removing it as all would fix your issue ?

Comment: No, removing the task causes additional errors. Refer to this link for reasons 
why.


https://forums.swift.org/t/crash-on-async-function-calls/59392

Comment: Actually you should get `Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled`. And the `do - catch` block in `load_noteBrowserScreen` is pointless as the function `throws`. And please, this is Swift: No underscore characters in function and variable names.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the answer to the problem above was conflicting class names. There is the built-in Task with swift, and there was a Task.swift class, which was throwing a conflict, and by renaming that class removed the above errors.

Thanks everyone for your time offering suggestions.